# Apply A list of filters to IEnumerable Data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, blazor

I have Data as  **IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>** and I have A list of filters  as **List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>**

This how OrginalData [image]

i am Trying to filter the data with  whatever in the list i used this function :

```cs
public IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> OrginalData { get; set; }

public void RunFilter()
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Region", "UK"));
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Region", "US"));
    
    FilterData(OrginalData, list);
}

private void FilterData(IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> OrginalDataSet, List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> filters)
{
    IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> Inresult = OrginalDataSet;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> filter in filters)
    {
        Inresult = Inresult.Where(x => (x as Dictionary<string, object>).Values.Any(d => filter.Value.Equals(d)));
    }

    GridData = Inresult;
}
```

the final output is keep replacing the original data form the loop
how i can append or add the result to the final data ?

Thanks

Comment: This is a great example of how you might do TDD. Define your test cases first, and build the code that satisfies the test cases. If you don't know how to write the code, then at least you have test cases that you can post here. Right now it's hard for people to guess at how you want your code to work.

Comment: Append `ToList()`

Comment: I edited as per  Kurt Hamilton Requsted

Comment: Is `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>` what you really want?  This is a collection of ``IDictionary` objects.  Note: `IDictionary` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`.  Can you add what `OrginalData` looks like?

Comment: this the OrginalData {System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>>}

Comment: Add Screenshot of the OrginalData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on MrC aka Shaun Curtis Senario the issue is resolved by do some change
now this can be applid more filters for the same keys with different values.

```
 @page "/"

<label>Country1</label>
<select class="form-select mb-3" @bind="_selectedCountry1" >
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="UK">UK</option>
</select>

<label>Country2</label>
<select class="form-select mb-3" @bind="_selectedCountry2">
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="UK">UK</option>
    <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
</select>


<button onclick="@GetFilters">Run Filters</button>

@if (_filteredDataSet.Count() == 0)
{
    <div class="m-2">No Matching Results</div>
}
@foreach (var item in _filteredDataSet)
{
    <div class="m-2">Name: @item["Name"]</div>
}



@code {
    private IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> _filteredDataSet = Enumerable.Empty<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    private string _selectedCountry1 = "UK";
    private string _selectedCountry2 = "France";

    private void OnSelect()
    {
        this.GetFilters();
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        
    }

    private void GetFilters()
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
        list.Clear();
        _filteredDataSet = Enumerable.Empty<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Country", _selectedCountry1));
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Country", _selectedCountry2));
        // list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Country", "UK"));
       //  list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Country", "French"));

        var query = DataSet.AsEnumerable();

        foreach (var filter in list)
        {

           var queryx = query.Where(item => item[filter.Key].Equals(filter.Value));

            _filteredDataSet = _filteredDataSet.Union(queryx);


           

        }
       
    }

    private List<IDictionary<string, object>> DataSet = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>()
    {
         new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "Name","David" },
            { "Country","UK" },
            { "Region", "Europe" },
            { "Nationality", "French" },
        },
         new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "Name","Fred" },
            { "Country","UK" },
            { "Region", "Europe" },
            { "Nationality", "British" },
        },
         new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "Name","Cecile" },
            { "Country","France" },
            { "Region", "Europe" },
            { "Nationality", "French" },
        },
         new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "Name","Amelie" },
            { "Country","France" },
            { "Region", "Europe" },
            { "Nationality", "French" },
        },
         new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "Name","Manuel" },
            { "Country","France" },
            { "Region", "Europe" },
            { "Nationality", "Spanish" },
        },

           new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "Name","Test1" },
            { "Country","Spain" },
            { "Region", "Europe" },
            { "Nationality", "Spanish" },
        },
           new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "Name","Test2" },
            { "Country","Spain" },
            { "Region", "Europe" },
            { "Nationality", "Spanish" },
        },
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Demo `Home` page that builds out the filter.  I think your main issue is in how you are constructing your queries.

You will run into problems when `object` is a reference object rather than a value object.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<label>Country</label>
<select class="form-select mb-3" @bind="_selectedCountry" @bind:after="OnSelect">
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="UK">UK</option>
</select>

<label>Nationality</label>
<select class="form-select mb-3" @bind="_selectedNationality" @bind:after="OnSelect">
    <option value="British">British</option>
    <option value="French">French</option>
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>

@if(_filteredDataSet.Count() == 0)
{
    <div class="m-2">No Matching Results</div>
}
@foreach( var item in _filteredDataSet)
{
<div class="m-2">Name: @item["Name"]</div>    
}



@code {
    private IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> _filteredDataSet = Enumerable.Empty<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    private string _selectedCountry = "UK";
    private string _selectedNationality = "French";

    private void OnSelect()
    {
        this.GetFilters();
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.GetFilters();
    }

    private void GetFilters()
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Country", (object)_selectedCountry));
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Nationality", _selectedNationality));
        //list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Country", "France"));
        //list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Nationality", "French"));

        var query = DataSet.AsEnumerable();

        foreach (var filter in list)
            query = query.Where(item => item[filter.Key].Equals(filter.Value));

        _filteredDataSet = query;

    }

    private List<IDictionary<string, object>> DataSet = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>()
    {
         new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "Name","David" },
            { "Country","UK" },
            { "Region", "Europe" },
            { "Nationality", "French" },
        },
         new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "Name","Fred" },
            { "Country","UK" },
            { "Region", "Europe" },
            { "Nationality", "British" },
        },
         new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "Name","Cecile" },
            { "Country","France" },
            { "Region", "Europe" },
            { "Nationality", "French" },
        },
         new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "Name","Amelie" },
            { "Country","France" },
            { "Region", "Europe" },
            { "Nationality", "French" },
        },
         new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "Name","Manuel" },
            { "Country","France" },
            { "Region", "Europe" },
            { "Nationality", "Spanish" },
        },
    };
}
```

Comment: Thnak you MrC aka Shaun Curtis this give the same result  what about if the filter list like this     list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Country", "UK"));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Country", "French"))

Comment: If you want to add the query to an existing `IEnumerable` I believe you can use `Union` - `_filteredDataSet.Union(query);`

Comment: _filteredDataSet  0 item